# RefreshIndicator triggers InkWell onTap()

Tags: flutter

I have a list in my app. The items in this list should be clickable. To achieve this, I wrapped the items in an `InkWell` and implemented the `onTap` event.

I need pull-to-refresh to update the list, so I wrapped the entire list in a `RefreshIndicator`. However, when I pull to refresh, the `onTap` event is triggered on the item that I finish the pull gesture on.

How can I prevent this from happening? I want to receive the `onTap` event only if I actually **tap** an item, not if I release the pull-to-refresh gesture.

The code looks like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: RefreshIndicator(
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final item = listData.elementAt(index);
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () { print("Tapped"); },
                child: SpecializedListItemWidget(forItem: item),
              );
            },
            childCount: listData.length,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    onRefresh: () async => await _updateList(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Is pull-to-refresh working?

Comment: @vedantkulkarni Yes. It's just that I'm getting an additional onTap call on the `InkWell`, which of course I don't want.